# What is the Tkinter grid layout manager behaviour with identical row & column?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm looking over documentation of Tkinter and I'm curious what the behaviour of widgets is when they have an identical row and column using the `grid` layout manager.

---

As far as I can tell, this is the most detailed explanation on the web:

> ### Columns and Rows
>
> Using grid, widgets are assigned a "column" number and a "row" number, which indicates their relative position to each other. **All widgets in the same column will therefore be above or below each other, while those in the same row will be to the left or right of each other.**
>
> Column and row numbers must be integers, with the first column and row starting at 0. You can leave gaps in column and row numbers (e.g. column 0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21), which is handy if you plan to add more widgets in the middle of the user interface at a later time.
>
> The width of each column (or height of each row) depends on the width or height of the widgets contained within the column or row. This means when sketching out your user interface, and dividing it into rows and columns, you don't need to worry about each column or row being equal width.
>
> *(Retrieved Nov 21, 2018 from https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html)*
>
> *[Emphasis Mine]*

---

However it doesn't make clear what happens for widgets **in the same column *and* row**. There also don't seem to be [`grid(**options)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method) that can specify where in the cell conflicting widgets get placed, though `sticky` might have some interaction.

Does Tkinter's `grid` layout manager place "colliding" widgets in declared order, left-to-right and top-to-bottom? How does the cell containing multiple widgets behave when the root widget (usually a frame or window) is resized? Is there a mechanism to override the default behaviour when collisions occur?

---

EDIT: The code I used to test the behaviour. Only the final label one seems to be displayed.

```
import tkinter, random

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Widget Collision Test - Grid Layout')

labels = []
for i in range(3):
    labels.append(tkinter.Label(root, text=str(i+1)))
    labels[i].grid(
        row=0, column=0,
        padx=50, pady=50,
        sticky=random.choice('N W S E'.split()))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Couldn't you just try it yourself and see what happens?

Comment: @martineau Yes, but then there also wouldn't be documentation on the behaviour anywhere online. I just finished testing and it seems like only the final widget in the cell is shown. `sticky` also seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Tkinter's grid layout manager place "colliding" widgets in declared order, left-to-right and top-to-bottom?

It does not place widgets in the same cell relative to each other. They are in effect stacked on top of each other, with the widget with the higher stacking order potentially obscuring widgets with a lower stacking order.

> How does the cell containing multiple widgets behave when the root widget (usually a frame or window) is resized?

The fact that there may be two widgets in a single cell doesn't affect the resize behavior at all. All widgets adjust according to the normal rules of the grid manager.

> Is there a mechanism to override the default behaviour when collisions occur?

No. If you want control over multiple widgets in a single grid cell, you should put those widgets in a frame, and then put that single frame within the grid cell. This gives you complete control over the widgets relative to each other within that frame.